# error sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: false

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting this error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: false`. I tried searching, but there seems to be no clear explanation and solution to this error for a newbie like me.

Please help.

```py
def getViolationsFromCam(self, cam, cleared=False):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        command = "SELECT camera.location, cars.id, cars.color, cars.first_sighted, cars.license_image, " \
                  " cars.license_number, cars.car_image, cars.num_rules_broken, cars.owner," \
                  " rules.name, rules.fine, violations.time, rules.id" \
                  " FROM violations, rules, cars, camera" \
                  " where rules.id = violations.rule" \
                  " and cars.id = violations.car" \
                  " and violations.camera = camera.id"
        if cam is not None:
            command = command + " and violations.camera = '" + str(cam) + "'"
        if cleared:
            command = command + " and violations.cleared = true"
        else:
            command = command + " and violations.cleared = false"

        cur.execute(command)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL but the error message includes SQLite? And what's the structure of `violations`?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I would bet a coin that the value of `cam` was `False` at the time of the error.

Comment: What version of sqlite are you using? true and false were added in 3.23.

Comment: (In older versions, use 1 and 0.)

Comment: thank you so much it i changed true and false to 1 and 0 and it worked